# Botão ao clicar pisca azulado

Tags: javascript, html

Criei 3 botoes (aplicação web), o problema é que quando clico neles(nos botoes) **na tela do celular** a area da **div** do botão fica azulada (acende e apaga). O curioso é que quando clico com o mouse pelo computador não acontece, funciona normalmente. Alguem sabe o por que?

HTML

```
<div id="botaoPause" class="botao alinhar centralizar">
   <i class="fas fa-pause"></i>
</div>


<div id="botaoStop" class="botao alinhar centralizar">
   <i class="fas fa-stop"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso é recurso do aparelho para realçar que algo foi clicado (ou tocado).

Comment: Acredito que não, por que se fosse em outros sites teria o mesmo efeito, e já testei, não acontece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte propriedade CSS para o elemento:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

> **-webkit-tap-highlight-color** é uma propriedade CSS não padrão que define a cor do destaque que aparece sobre um link enquanto ele está sendo tocado. O realce indica ao usuário que seu toque está sendo reconhecido com sucesso e indica em qual elemento ele está tocando.

Veja este link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

Comment: Isso cara, deu certo. Valeu!